# To check if any incoming emails for a specific Email-to-Case in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, sfdc

The requirement is to check if any incoming emails for a specific Email-to-Case.
If the incoming email is for a new case restrict them to create a new case and auto-reply email should be sent.
If the email is associated with an existing case, the email should be added to the existing case.
P.S. There are many Routing Addresses already exists in Email-to-Case.

Comment: So? What have you tried, which piece of code are you stuck with?